# Drag and Drop UI layouts using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, layout, drag-and-drop

For our next project (a small app in ASP.NET/C#) we have to create drag and drop zones in the UI so that components/widgets can be dragged and dropped and layouts can be changed dynamically (for example, the user should be able to switch between two-column to a three-column layout from the front end).

After doing some searching, I got to know that there are two approaches:

1. Use Web parts and Content-zones.
2. Using jQuery.

I also learnt that jQuery approach is preffered, but I would like to know how can I create such zones in my application and also save these zones per user (in the D so that when the new request comes for that user their preferred layout is displayed? I basically want to know if there are some tutorials on creating persistable drag and drop zones using jQuery.

Thanks,

Mohit Kumar

Comment: But how do I persist the current layout in the DB? Is there something like "content zone" in jQuery? I want to change the layout from 2 to 3 column? how do I persist the layout per user in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know my answer would be useful to you or not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

You can use :

- 1) [jQuery Drag & Drop Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/drag-and-drop),
- 2) [DRAG-AND-DROP](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/drag-and-drop)

for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggested use [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) & [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) from the jQuery API.

[Here](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/saving-state-for-collapsible-drag-drop-panels/) is an example how to actually do the post and save the layout. Server side saving is in the example done in php, but it can any other language also.

There is a JavaScript function called `updateWidgetData()` that you might like to investigate. It collects all the information to the array and uses `$.post` to send the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `draggable() and droppable` methods of jquery.

see this [reference](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable)